# I'm using Sqlite for my android app and i want to order my Db by the value in score column from highest to lowest

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

I'm using Sqlite for my android app and i want to order my Db by the value in score column from highest to lowest.

I'm using this method

```
Cursor cur = query ("Gamestable", String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

Not sure how to fill in the rest.

Comment: SUGGESTION: try using a SQL query string like `db.execSQL("select player,scores from Gamestable order by scores desc")`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is sorting from highest to lowest use this query

```
Cursor cur = query ("Gamestable", null, null, null, null, null, SCORE_VALUE + "DESC", null);

if(cur != null)
    cur.moveToFirst();
```

where SCORE_VALUE is the name of your column where the score is stored.

This is the simplest query possible, it's better to use a selection in the second field instead of using `null` choosing only the columns you want to be returned.